# Android to Android device communication through the internet(wifi or 3g)?

Tags: android, communication, messaging, android-wifi, 3g

What is the best way for an Android app installed on two devices to communicate with each other in the internet(wifi or 3g)? Is Google Cloud Messaging is the correct path and what are the other ways?

Comment: Did you forgot Wifi, Bluetooth, NFC, for limited range.

Comment: My program is to retrieve the other device location. I had check that you can retrieve it through text. But I have no idea to retrieve the location data through internet. I don't really need limited range device.